# How to display text from database in code.org?

Tags: database, display, code.org

I am new to stackoverflow and my name is Aarav Agarwal. So I wanted to ask that how do you display text from database in code.org? Please help in this [project](https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/WK4uuvqqQ8eH4Ijl7jeFhKjHXplaQ2QsJ-7My1uuFaQ). I wanna display the username user has input at the top of screen 2. Please help me with the projet.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you still need help with this, but I would use var item = getText(""); with the name of your dropdown and maybe a different name for the variable. I would then use a setText with the name of the variable (out of quotes) and the name of the box you want to display it in (in quotes). Hope this helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).